# SSIS Getting the most up to date record using datetime columns

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I am building an SSIS for SQL Server 2014 package and currently  trying to get the most recent record from 2 different sources using datetime columns between the two sources and implementing a method to accomplish that. So far I am using a Lookup Task on thirdpartyid to match the records that I need to eventually compare and using a Merge Join to bring them together and eventually have a staging table that has the most recent record.I have a previous data task, not shown that already inserts records that are not in AD1 into a staging table so at this point these records are a one to one match. Both sources look like this with the exact same datetime columns just different dates and some information having null values as there is no history of it.

Sample output

[image: Table Output]

This is my data flow task [image: Data Flow Task] so far. I am really new to SSIS so any ideas or suggestions  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can a record exist only in v1? Can it exist only in AD1? Can a record in V1 match more than one row in AD1 (and the converse)?

Comment: Generally speaking, add explicit order by statements in your sources to save the cost of sorting within you data flow. Once the sources are sending it as sorted, then you can go into the advanced properties of the source components and mark it as such.

Comment: I will include that order by clause thank you and I clarified better in the question on the matching records. At this point there will be a one to one match on V1 and AD1. @billinkc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that there is a 1:1 match between your two sources, I would structure this as an Source (V1) -> Lookup  (AD1)

Define your lookup based on `thirdpartyid` and retrieve all the AD1 columns. You'll likely end up with data flow look like like `name` and `name_ad1`, etc

I would then add a Derived Column that identifies if the dates are different (assuming in that situation, you need to take action)

```
IsNull(LastUpdated_AD1) || LastUpdated > LastUpdated_AD1
```

That expression would create a boolean if the column in AD1 is null or if the V1 last updated column is greater than the AD1 version.

You'd likely then add a Conditional Split into your Data Flow and base it on the value of our new column and then route the changed data into your mechanism for handling updates (OLE DB Command or preferably, an OLE DB Destination + an Execute SQL Task post Data Flow to perform an batch update)

The comment asks

> should it all be one expression? like `IsNull(AssignmentLastUpdated_AD1) || AssignmentLastUpdated > AssignmentLastUpdated_AD1 || IsNull(RoomLastUpdated_AD1) || RoomLastUpdated > RoomLastUpdated_AD1`

You *can* do it like that but when you get a weird result and someone asks how you got that value, long expressions make it hard to debug. I'd likely have two derived columns components in the data flow. The first would create a has changed column for each set of conditions

HasChangedAssignment

```
(IsNull(AssignmentLastUpdated_AD1) || AssignmentLastUpdated > AssignmentLastUpdated_AD1)
```

HasChangedRoom

```
IsNull(RoomLastUpdated_AD1) || RoomLastUpdated > RoomLastUpdated_AD1
```

etc

And then in the final derived column, you create the HasChanged column

```
HasChangedAssignment || HasChangedRoom || HasChangedAdNauseum
```

Using a pattern based approach like this makes it much easier to build, troubleshoot and/or or make small changes that can have a big impact to the correctness, maintainability and performance of your packages.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback for the derived column should it all be one expression? like IsNull(AssignmentLastUpdated_AD1) || AssignmentLastUpdated > AssignmentLastUpdated_AD1 || IsNull(RoomLastUpdated_AD1) || RoomLastUpdated > RoomLastUpdated_AD1 @Billinkc